# file extension .kt ? What kind of file is this?

Tags: windows, file-extension

I am currently working on a project in which I came across files with extension .kt I am not able to figure out which tool can I use to know the contents of the file. I would be glad to if you can tell what .kt file actually mean and when is it used ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

it might be from/for Kotlin:
http://kotlin.jetbrains.org/
it's a source code file for a programming language which "is a statically typed programming language that compiles to JVM byte codes and JavaScript." (according to their website)